# tmux 8-pane "sane" tiled layout

Tags: tmux

When I use `tmux` with 8 panes it tiles them like this:

[image]

But I want them tiled like this:

[image]

Any way to accomplish this automatically?

Comment: I doubt it (unless you alter the underlying code).  Seems hardwired.  I like the six equal sized ones.  I can see how eight would be good -- but I don't think it is there yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below bash script:

```
tmux new -s test -d

tmux selectp -t 0    # select the first (0) pane
tmux splitw -h -p 75 # split it into two horizontal parts
tmux selectp -t 0    # select the first (0) pane
tmux splitw -v -p 50 # split it into two vertical halves

# After this 3 panes will be created with pane number 0 (left- horizontal)
# Pane 1 (vertical pane under the pane 0)
# And Pane 2 with the remaining screen size 
# Then we divide this remaining pane 2 into three similar panes
# repeat this till all 8 panes are created

tmux selectp -t 2    # select the new, second (2) pane
tmux splitw -h -p 66 # split it into two halves
tmux selectp -t 2    # select the second (2) pane
tmux splitw -v -p 50 # split it into two vertical halves

tmux selectp -t 4    # select the new, fourth (4) pane
tmux splitw -h -p 50 # split it into two halves
tmux selectp -t 4    # select the fourth (4) pane
tmux splitw -v -p 50 # split it into two halves

tmux selectp -t 6    # select the new, sixth (6) pane
tmux splitw -v -p 50 # split it into two halves
tmux selectp -t 0    # go back to the first pane
tmux attach -t test
```

The trick is to identify the `pane number` and split it accordingly.
Add the following lines to the above script and you can see the pane number and how it is arranged by the `tmux`.

```
tmux send-keys -t 0 'echo "-- Pane 1 ---"' Enter
tmux send-keys -t 1 'echo "-- Pane 2 ---"' Enter
tmux send-keys -t 2 'echo "-- Pane 3 ---"' Enter
tmux send-keys -t 3 'echo "-- Pane 4 ---"' Enter
tmux send-keys -t 4 'echo "-- Pane 5 ---"' Enter
tmux send-keys -t 5 'echo "-- Pane 6 ---"' Enter
tmux send-keys -t 6 'echo "-- Pane 7 ---"' Enter
tmux send-keys -t 7 'echo "-- Pane 8 ---"' Enter
```

`send-keys` will send the command `echo "-- pane number --"`  to the panes specified by `-t` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the panes yourself with the tmux command line:

```
tmux splitw -v -p 20 -t ssh_tmux:0.0 #splits window0, pane0 vertically
tmux splitw -h -p 80 -t ssh_tmux:0.1 #splits the lower pane horizontally
```

You'd have to play with `-p` which sets the relative widths of the panes, but you could write a bash script to to this with a single command.

TL;DR: I don't think there's an easy way, but it's not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The following `bash` script works for me:

```sh
tmux new -s logs -d
tmux splitw -v -p 50 -t logs:0.0
tmux splitw -h -p 75 -t logs:0.0
tmux splitw -h -p 66 -t logs:0.1
tmux splitw -h -p 50 -t logs:0.2
tmux splitw -h -p 75 -t logs:0.4
tmux splitw -h -p 66 -t logs:0.5
tmux splitw -h -p 50 -t logs:0.6
tmux attach -t logs
```